# What is the name for the software on the trackpad that detects thumbs vs palms?

Tags: touchpad

This [site](http://techblog.tthu.net/2015/01/apple-trackpadtouchpad-sensitivity-under-linux/) refers to problems switching from MacOS to Linux on a Mac Laptop - the problem being the palm detection software:

> The blog above also lists commands to get some other things working, these include two-finger and three-finger taps for right and middle clicks, corner buttons and palm detection.

I think there must be a category or a term for this kind of software.

(I'd really like to get it working on my Toshiba i7 running Win10 - but I want to know what it is called first).

My question is: **What is the name for the software on the trackpad that detects thumbs vs palms?**

Comment: You realize that Apple computers have the hardware required for palm detection and your Toshbia likely doesn't.  Any event if it has a Synpatics touch pad just install the Toshbia Synaptics drivers

Comment: Anyways there really isn't a "name" for it.  It's just a software package Synaptics creates for its hardware